# VBA Macro to fill dates until todays date is reached

Tags: vba, excel, date, macros

Biweekly, I have to update a report that fills the dates between the last report.  I am trying to get the macro to fill the dates between the last run report and stop at the current date.  I currently have this:

```
Sub IncreaseDate()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim myDate As Date
Dim row As Long

FirstDate = range("A1").value

NextDate = FirstDate

row = 1

Do Until myDate = Date
    myDate = myDate + 1
    range("A" & row).value = myDate
    row = row + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

But I don't really want the date to start at 1900.

Comment: it's dependent on year defined in`FirstDate = range("A1").value`

Answer (score 1):

```
MyDate = FirstDate

row = 1

Do Until myDate = Date
    myDate = myDate + 1
    range("A" & row).value = myDate
    row = row + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it in one fast step:

```
Sub test()
  Dim a As Long
  a = Range("A1").Value
  Range("A2:A" & CLng(Date - a + 1)).Value = Evaluate("Row(" & a + 1 & ":" & CLng(Date) & ")")
End Sub
```

just make sure the cells are formatted as date ;)